Prevent screen shot and screen record in MacOs and Windows - Flutter Desktop App
Where should I prevent both screenshots and screen recording? Currently, screenshot prevention is working fine, but I also need to restrict screen recording on macOS and Windows desktop apps.
The code provided is for macOS. If you have any solution for Windows as well, please share it for both platforms.
Thanks in Advance!!
your_flutter_project/macos/Runner/AppDelegate.swift
`import Cocoa
import FlutterMacOS

@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
  
  override func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
    let controller: FlutterViewController = mainFlutterWindow?.contentViewController as! FlutterViewController
    let screenshotBlockerChannel = FlutterMethodChannel(name: "screenshot_blocker", binaryMessenger: controller.engine.binaryMessenger)
    
    screenshotBlockerChannel.setMethodCallHandler { (call: FlutterMethodCall, result: @escaping FlutterResult) in
      if call.method == "disableScreenshots" {
        self.disableScreenshots(result: result)
      } else if call.method == "enableScreenshots" {
        self.enableScreenshots(result: result)
      } else {
        result(FlutterMethodNotImplemented)
      }
    }
    
    super.applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification)
  }

  // Disable Screenshots Logic
  private func disableScreenshots(result: FlutterResult) {
    if let window = mainFlutterWindow {
      // Setting the security level for the window
      window.sharingType = .none  // Disable window sharing (prevents some forms of screen capture)
      result(true)
    } else {
      result(FlutterError(code: "UNAVAILABLE", message: "Window not available", details: nil))
    }
  }

  // Enable Screenshots Logic (restore default behavior)
  private func enableScreenshots(result: FlutterResult) {
    if let window = mainFlutterWindow {
      // Restore window sharing behavior
      window.sharingType = .readWrite
      result(true)
    } else {
      result(FlutterError(code: "UNAVAILABLE", message: "Window not available", details: nil))
    }
  }
}

`
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
class ScreenshotBlocker {
  static const MethodChannel _channel = MethodChannel('screenshot_blocker');
  // Method to disable screenshots
  static Future<void> disableScreenshots() async {
    try {
      await _channel.invokeMethod('disableScreenshots');
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      print("Failed to disable screenshots: '${e.message}'.");
    }
  }
  // Method to enable screenshots (undo prevention)
  static Future<void> enableScreenshots() async {
    try {
      await _channel.invokeMethod('enableScreenshots');
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      print("Failed to enable screenshots: '${e.message}'.");
    }
  }
}

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  
    // To disable screenshots
    ScreenshotBlocker.disableScreenshots();
   
  }


Update the AppDelegate.swift:
private func restrictScreenRecording() {
    guard let window = mainFlutterWindow else { return }
    window.level = NSWindow.Level(CGShieldingWindowLevel())
    window.sharingType = .none
}

override func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
    let controller: FlutterViewController = mainFlutterWindow?.contentViewController as! FlutterViewController
    let screenshotBlockerChannel = FlutterMethodChannel(name: "screenshot_blocker", binaryMessenger: controller.engine.binaryMessenger)

    screenshotBlockerChannel.setMethodCallHandler { (call: FlutterMethodCall, result: @escaping FlutterResult) in
        if call.method == "disableScreenshots" {
            self.disableScreenshots(result: result)
            self.restrictScreenRecording()
        } else if call.method == "enableScreenshots" {
            self.enableScreenshots(result: result)
        } else {
            result(FlutterMethodNotImplemented)
        }
    }

    super.applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification)
}

For Windows Firstly
Create a new C++ file (ScreenBlocker.cpp) in your Windows project:
#include <Windows.h>
#include <flutter/flutter_view_controller.h>

void DisableScreenRecording() {
    
    SetProcessDPIAware();
}

Then Modify your existing Flutter Windows integration:
In your Runner.cpp, integrate these functions into your existing method channel setup:
void MethodChannelHandler(const std::string& method) {
    if (method == "disableScreenshots") {
        DisableScreenRecording();
    }
}


Thanks for the response. I tried it, but the screen is still being recorded in MacOs.

Thanks for sharing this nice feature
For mac os, this code works well to prevent screenshot
But it doesn't work when recording the screen and you can simply record the video from the application. Do you have a solution?

have modified to block ScreenRecording with window.level = NSWindow.Level(CGShieldingWindowLevel()); @Kiax

Thanks for your response. I'm not sure if I'm implementing the code correctly, as it's not working for me. Can you please verify if the code snippet is accurate?
private func restrictScreenRecording() {
guard let window = mainFlutterWindow else { return }
window.sharingType = .none
window.level = NSWindow.Level(Int(CGShieldingWindowLevel()))
}
